# How to remove the default margin-left from the span?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row-fluid like this

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span5"></div>
</div>
```

Now i need to remove the margin-left from span6... i tried doing it on the `bootstrap.css` file by setting `margin:0px` but this effects span5. How to effectively remove the margin-left from span6?

Regards,
Nasir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.span6 {
    margin: 0px; 
}
```

Just place it in your own custom CSS file that runs after the Bootstrap files.

Comment: I did that but it affects other spans

Comment: It can only affect other elements with class `span6`. You could add a class `no-margin` for example to the div where you want the margin removed and give that class `margin: 0;`.

Answer (score -1):

Overwrite the Css by using `!important`

```
.span6 {
    margin: 0px !important; 
}
```